# MySql : how to loop so i can get all perents of a recourd

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an id and parentID 
each row have parentID that exist in the same table so the rows are connected
and the most primordial row have parentID = 0
how can i get all the rows that are connected to each other in one call of sql?

so i wont have to request in a loop in the client side?

**[edit]**

it's kinda like a famliy tree

i have

id

name

parentID

so let say Adam is the grandfather
Dan is his son and jack is his grandson

1 Adam 0

2 Dan 1

3 Jack 2

and i only have Jack's ID
I want to get them all in one query
can it be done?

tnx 
Ali

Comment: What you are looking for is a `join` or a `nested query` depending on your table design (which from context is hard to tell). Google it, study it, apply it.

Comment: @Sophex can more detail like table structure and expected result.

Comment: In the future, please search for an answer before posting. When you do post, please include table structures, sample data, expected output, what you've tried, and why/how it didn't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: tnx guys didnt know how to find what i wanted